# Treeview insert property problem

Tags: c#, .net

```
TreeNode[] nodes = this.treeview.Nodes.Find(node.Text, true);
      if (nodes.Length > 0)
      {
        int i = nodes[0].Index;
        if (nodes.Length > 0)
          this.treeview.Nodes.Remove(nodes[0]);
        this.treeview.Nodes.Insert(i, nodes[0]);
      }
```

i tried this code,

but the node nodes[0] is not inserting into the particular index.

instead it is adding at the last.

but yes i use treeviewsorter.

Any idea how to insert node without using insert

or using insert effectively with treeviewsorter??

Comment: ...and format your code correctly

Comment: What are you trying accomplish? It seems you're looking for a node at every deep level, and you remove it just from the root level nodes. It sounds a bit strange to me...

Comment: I know the answer.  Hint: it's a tree.

Comment: As part of digEmAll's answer suggests, I think the problem is that your sorter is overriding any attempt to manually index items.  Although I am a bit confused why a (presumably sorted?) node @ index i wouldn't just go back to index i under the same sorting(wherever you tried to insert it), trying to manually index with a sorter in place seems contradictory.    It seems potentially like telling your tree to keep things sorted alphabetically and also move the "cactus" node above "banana"...it can't really do both, and the sorting seems specifically designed to prevent the latter from happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have set the `TreeViewNodeSorter` property to a custom comparer, your `TreeView` nodes will automatically be sorted using that comparer.

Thus, you can't insert a node in a different position, because the position is decided using the comparer.

But, in your specific case you're removing a node and inserting it back in its original position, and you say it doesn't work when actually it should do.

This, (I'm guessing) could be due to several reasons:

1. Your comparer implementation is wrong, or peraphs it uses a property that depends on the sorting itself (like `Node.Index`)
2. The node you get with `Find()` (supposing is just one...), belongs to a level lower than root, but you try to remove it from root nodes and add to that level...
3. Other reasons, we need more code...